# Signing a DLL assembly with public key token

Tags: c#, .net, dll, strongname, assembly-signing

I inherited a C# .NET application that needed slight modifications to some of the path name strings in one of the DLL assemblies. I do not have the source code, unfortunately.

I made the necessary modifications using ILSpy and the Reflexil plugin. When I save the DLL, I'm told the original file was signed and that the new file won't work without it being signed. The new file is now "delay signed".

I can see the public key, the public key token and the hash algorithm with Reflexil.

I'm totally new to .NET IL. How can I use the public key information I have to sign the patched DLL?

I have Visual Studio 2013, so have access to sn.exe, if that helps.

Comment: If you could do that, the whole signing process would be entirely useless. The only way is to remove the signing altogether (which might well propagate through several assemblies). You'll need the private key to sign the assembly properly.

Comment: @Luaan I can create a private key from my machine. Will that help, or does it have to be the original private key?

Comment: That depends on what you're trying to do. It might be just fine to leave the assembly without a signature. It might be fine to create your own key and sign with that. But in both cases, you'll have a different assembly - any assemblies that reference it will have to be recompiled (well, their references will have to change). The signature is part of the assembly's identity - you wouldn't want someone to give you their own mscorlib that would silently replace your own references to mscorlib, would you?

Comment: @Luaan Ok, thanks. If I remove the strong name with Reflexil and use its AutoScan assembly tool to detect what other files need the strong name removed, it only brings up the main application. So I guess the only thing to do is to remove the strong name and see how the program behaves.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Better yet, that person should have said something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Luaan said above, what I wanted to do is not possible. The private key is just that - private. The public key is designed for verification purposes, to ensure that the assembly has not been modified.

Removing the strong name was an option, as Luaan said in one of his comments. This did not work for me, however, as there were many dependencies, making the method impractical.

As a temporary solution, I've left the assembly file delay signed, and disabled strong name validation in the registry for the DLL concerned.

To disable strong name validation, add this key to the registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\StrongName\Verification\<filename without extension>,<public key token>
```

For 64-bit systems, you need to add this key as well:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\StrongName\Verification\<filename without extension>,<public key token>
```

Note that disabling strong name validation is recommended for testing purposes only, as this could represent a security issue.

Comment: This worked. Wow.  I added EntityFramework source code to my project, removed all references to old EntityFramework.dll and added references to the project instead. Every attempt to run the code failed with a signing error.  Then I added the key for 64-bit systems, exactly as described above, ran my project, and like magic... I'm now stepping into the EntityFramework source code.  No computer restarts or anything necessary. THANK YOU.